# How to Pandas read_csv multiple records per line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iterator

(I'm a pandas n00b) I have some oddly formatted CSV data that resembles this:

```
i   A           B           C       
    x   y   z   x   y   z   x   y   z
-------------------------------------
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
2   1   2   3   3   2   1   2   1   3
3   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1
```

where `A`, `B`, `C` are categorical and the properties `x`, `y`, `z` are present for each. What I *think* I want to do (part of a larger [split-apply-combine](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#group-by-split-apply-combine) step) is to read data with Pandas such that I have dimensionally homogenous *observations* like this:

```
i   id  GRP   x   y   z
-----------------------
1   1   A     1   2   3
2   1   B     4   5   6
3   1   C     7   8   9
4   2   A     1   2   3
5   2   B     3   2   1
6   2   C     2   1   3
7   3   A     9   8   7
8   3   B     6   5   4
9   3   C     3   2   1
```

#### So how *best* to accomplish this?

**#1**: I thought about reading the file using basic [`read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking) options, then iterating/ slicing/transposing/whatever to create *another* dataframe that has the structure i want. But in my case the number of categories (`A`,`B`,`C`) and properties (`x`,`y`,`z`) is large *and* is not known ahead of time. I'm also worried about memory issues if scaling to large datasets.

**#2**: I like the idea of setting the `iterator` param in `read_csv()` and then yielding multiple observations per line. (any reason y not set [chunksize=1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)?) I wouldn't be creating multiple dataframes this way at least.

What's the smarter way to do this?

Comment: Can I see EXACTLY the output of data from this: `data = []; with open(filename) as f: [data.append(f.readline()) for _ in range(5)]` where filename is obviously the path to your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I constructed the sample dataframe like yours:

```
column = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['x', 'y', 'z']],
                       labels=[[i for i in range(3) for _ in range(3)], [0, 1, 2]*3])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, size=(3, 9)),
                  columns=column, index=[1, 2, 3])

print df

#    A        B        C      
#    x  y  z  x  y  z  x  y  z
# 1  5  7  4  7  7  8  9  1  9
# 2  8  5  1  8  5  9  4  4  2
# 3  4  9  6  2  1  4  6  1  6
```

To get your desired output, reshape the dataframe using `df.stack()` and then reset the index:

```
df = df.stack(0).reset_index()

df.index += 1    # to make index begin from 1

print df

#    level_0 level_1  x  y  z
# 1        1       A  5  7  4
# 2        1       B  7  7  8
# 3        1       C  9  1  9
# 4        2       A  8  5  1
# 5        2       B  8  5  9
# 6        2       C  4  4  2
# 7        3       A  4  9  6
# 8        3       B  2  1  4
# 9        3       C  6  1  6
```

Then you can just rename the columns as you want. Hope it helps.

Comment: tnx! When u init the df tho, what is purpose of `size` kwarg? Not seeing this param in v0.18 [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame).

Comment: nm. not paying close enough attention to paren groupings.